# jQuery UI autocomplete with aliases

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery UI Autocomplete in my form and everything's working fine (thanks to the community).
There's just one thing left to make it perfect... aliases.

The autocompleted field is for the user to enter his country. One autocomplete option is "United States of America". How can I do it such that if the user types in the acronym "USA", the autocompleter associates it with the "United States of America" value?

In other words, is there a way to create an alias when I define the countries in my list (countries variable)?
list:

```
var countries = [
  "United States of America",
  "United Kingdom",
  // ...
]
```

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Why is this question a word-for-word clone of a 10+ year old topic from the jQuery forum? https://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-aliases

Comment: Because there is just one answer and it's not helping. It could be more useful for people to have this answer on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with alias..

```js
var tags = ["United States of America", "United Kingdom", "South Africa", "Albany"];
var alias = ["usa", "uk", "sa", "youpi"];
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var ids = alias.indexOf(request.term);

    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response($.grep(tags, function(item, i) {
      if(ids == i) return true;
      return matcher.test(item);
    }));    
  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <label for="autocomplete">Select Something </label>
  <input id="autocomplete">


</body>

</html>
```

Here is one idea, after you adapt the code easily, following what you want