# jQuery autocomplete with aliases from dictionary

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

This previous question from 2021 ([jQuery UI autocomplete with aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66369579/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-aliases)) was a solution to an old question, but I'm trying to include the aliases within the dictionary instead of using two arrays.The idea is that I can use the alias or the value for lookup and save the ID for the entry. I was trying to reverse engineer the previous array solution but to no success. The below code is the working, basic autocomplete to use the dictionary, lookup the value, and return the key. I can't figure out how to implement the matching part.

```
var dict = [{key:'1', value:'United States of America', alias:'usa'},
            {key:'2', value:'United Kingdom', alias:'uk'},
            {key:'3', value:'South Africa', alias:'sa'}]

$( "#txtValue" ).autocomplete({
    source: dict,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(ui.item.key);
        }
    });
```

This is the original solution for two arrays:

```
var tags = ["United States of America", "United Kingdom", "South Africa"];
var alias = ["usa", "uk", "sa"];

$( "#txtValue" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
    var ids = alias.indexOf(request.term);
    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response($.grep(tags, function(item, i) {
        if(ids == i) return true;
        return matcher.test(item);
    }));    
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(ui.item.label);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s96zeq8b/ updated with Patrick's code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your trying to do, but do you even need to use a match you can get everything from the selected array item i.e : the key, value and alias not the console log demo

EDIT: fix for the match using alias

```js
var dict = [{key:'1',value:'United States of America',alias:'usa'},
             {key:'2',value:'United Kingdom',alias:'uk'},
             {key:'3',value:'South Africa',alias:'sa'}
]

$(document).ready(function () {
    
    
$( "#txtValue2" ).autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {
          let res = dict.filter(function(value, index) {
            return request.term === value.alias;
          });
          let ids = parseInt(res && res.length && res[0].key || -1) - 1;
          let matcher = new RegExp("^" +
            $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
          response($.grep(dict, function(item, i) {
            //console.log(matcher.test(item.alias))
            if (ids == i) return true;
            return matcher.test(item.alias);
          }));
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
          console.log(ui.item.key);
        }
      });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>autocomplete alias</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-lSjKY0/srUM9BE3dPm+c4fBo1dky2v27Gdjm2uoZaL0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <style>
        .custom-combobox {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        .custom-combobox-toggle {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          margin-left: -1px;
          padding: 0;
        }
        .custom-combobox-input {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 5px 10px;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body><br><br>
    Dictionary: <input type="text" class="form" id="txtValue2">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i need to be able to use the value or the alias for lookup and store the id value

Comment: nailed it. this is exactly what i was trying to accomplish

Comment: cool glad I was able to help, sorry took so long for me to get there though

Answer (score 0):

ah ok fair enough then i believe this should be what your after, it dose the same as your old script but using the `dict` array instead

Note this assumes the key value will match the corresponding value in the alias array based on the index of an item in that array matching the the key value

```
  $("#txtValue").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      let res = dict.filter(function(value, index) {
        return request.term === value.alias;
      });
      let ids = parseInt(res && res.length && res[0].key || -1) - 1;
      let matcher = new RegExp("^" +
        $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
      response($.grep(tags, function(item, i) {
        if (ids == i) return true;
        return matcher.test(item);
      }));
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.item.label);
    }
  });
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I had to replace tags with the dict variable in the grep line. it worked once, but then stopped working.

Comment: sorry not sure I fully understand, I have posted a working example using the match and dict for you, let me know if that helps ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vLs59tfw/ 
You can see here how it's supposed to go but not working.

Comment: ah ok i think I see what you mean, sorry that's my bad just change line ```return matcher.test(item);``` to ```return matcher.test(item.alias);```, that should fix the match sorry about that will update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this demonstrates the use of the dict

```js
var tags = ["United States of America", "United Kingdom", "South Africa", "Albany"];
var alias = ["usa", "uk", "sa", "youpi"];

var dict = [{
    key: '1',
    value: 'United States of America',
    alias: 'usa'
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    value: 'United Kingdom',
    alias: 'uk'
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    value: 'South Africa',
    alias: 'sa'
  }
]

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#txtValue").autocomplete({
    //    source: dict2,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var ids = alias.indexOf(request.term);

      var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
      response($.grep(tags, function(item, i) {
        if (ids == i) return true;
        return matcher.test(item);
      }));
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.item.label);
    }
  });

  $("#txtValue2").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      let res = dict.filter(function(value, index) {
        return request.term === value.alias;
      });
      let ids = parseInt(res && res.length && res[0].key || -1) - 1;
      let matcher = new RegExp("^" +
        $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
      response($.grep(dict, function(item, i) {
        if (ids == i) return true;
        return matcher.test(item);
      }));
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.item.key);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>autocomplete alias</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-lSjKY0/srUM9BE3dPm+c4fBo1dky2v27Gdjm2uoZaL0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <style>
        .custom-combobox {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
        }
        .custom-combobox-toggle {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          margin-left: -1px;
          padding: 0;
        }
        .custom-combobox-input {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 5px 10px;
        }
        </style>
</head>
<body><br><br>
   Array: <input type="text" class="form" id="txtValue">
    Dictionary: <input type="text" class="form" id="txtValue2">
</body>
</html>
```